# Redirect apache (2.2)

Tags: git, apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a problem since a few day that I find hard to solve :(

I use gitweb to show through http the content of my git projects. However, I don't want that anyone can access to the root folder of all projects.

The UI of my https server allow the fact to point each project in terms of access rights :

/var/lib/gitroot/git-module-test1 --> https//server.org/gitweb/?p=git-module-test1;a=summary
/var/lib/gitroot/git-module-test2 --> https//server.org/gitweb/?p=git-module-test2;a=summary
etc ...

So I want to avoid the access of https//server.org/gitweb/

here is the config of /etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb.conf

```
Alias /gitweb /usr/share/gitweb

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^/gitweb/$  / [L] # Is not working
#RewriteRule ^/gitweb$  / [L] # Is not working

Redirect "/gitweb/$" "https//server.org"  # Does not redirect anything !!
#Redirect "/gitweb/" "https//server.org"  # Redirect all !

<Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
  Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

Please, how can I do ????

Answer (score 0):

Redirect redirects all and does not take regex, if you want a specific url to be redirected and not its subdirectories or anything else you use RedirectMatch with an anchor like

```
RedirectMatch ^/gitweb/$ https//server.org/
```

^ <-- marks the beggining of the string to match
$ <-- marks the end of the string to match